# How to parse json with readEntity when REST api returns 404

Tags: rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

The Silverpop REST API returns a JSON message like this:

```
{
"meta": {
    "attributes": {},
    "generalErrors": ["Consent not found"],
    "fieldErrors": {},
    "links": [],
    "nextPageUrl": null
},
"data": null
}
```

If it doesnt find a record, it returns 404 with the above JSON but with

> "generalErrors": ["Contact not found"]

If the URL is missing a parameter it returns 404 with

> "generalErrors": ["Parameter not found"]

If the database is not found (a major error) it returns 404 with

> "generalErrors": ["Database not found"]

In my code, I am trying to parse the response JSON into an object, but the problem is the parse simply doesnt do it if the response is 404. I need get the response into an object so I can parse out the error message and decide what to do from there (i.e. work out if its contact not found, which is normal, or an error).  The code is like this:

```
RestApiResponseDO responseDO = response.readEntity(RestApiResponseDO.class);
```

If the status is 404, the resultant `responseDo` is empty (no fields set)

Is there a way to force it to parse the response no matter what the status code?

Another strategy might be to read the response into a string, then parse the string.  However, the `readEndity` does not take a string, so presume it has to be converted back into a stream or similar?  Has one one done this?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a `Error` class that you `response.readEntity(Error.class)` form, 
if `response.statusCode == 404`, else you proceed as you currently do.
`Error` could also be an abstract type or interface, that specializes into `ConsentNotFoundError` or `ParameterNotFoundError`. Or it could be a concrete type returning an enum like `SilverpopErrors.CONSENT_NOT_FOUND`.

I am wondering why a "Database not found" returns an `404`, 4xx signals the 
client did something wrong, but a database related error would be a 5xx.
A missing URL in the request should be a `400` Bad Request.